# TSQL Delete from table based on foreign key

Tags: t-sql

I have three tables Table A, B, C. Table A has a foreign key that points to Table B. Table B has a foreign key that points to Table C. I want to delete a record in Table A where the linked Table B's linked Table C's Id value is equal to a certain value. What would be an example for a query that does this?

Comment: Do you mean Table A points to Table B and Table B points to Table C?

Comment: @iamdave Yes, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a bit odd, but simple enough to understand:

```
delete a
from TableA a
    inner join TableB b
        on a.FK = b.PK
    inner join TableC c
        on b.FK = c.PK
where c.ID = 'A Certain Value'
```